# Is there a limit in Chrome for the maximum amount of audio tags?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

The task at hand is to play a large number of audio tracks in a browser: 16, for example. This works properly in Firefox, Microsoft Edge, but does not work in Chrome Desktop or Chrome Mobile.

**The source code:**

```
<div class="audios">
    <!-- repeat 16 times -->
    <audio controls="true"> <source src="..." type="..."> </audio>
</div>
```

**Environment notes**

- To avoid reaching the limit for maximum parallel connections, all of the audio files are delivered from different domains
- The files are in .m4a format

**Expected and working**

On page load, metedata is loaded asynchronously for all of the tracks, then, when you click the play buttons on each of the audio elements, the audio data is buffered and played.

**Chrome behavior**

Chrome loads letadata for a maximum of 10 elements, then is able to play all of them back. Requests for the rest of the audio files are left `(pending)` in Network tab. Seeking, pausing and playing the stalled audios does not trigger any additional network activity.

**Things I've tried**

- Removing loaded audio tags does not start loading on stalled audios
- Setting `<audio>` `preload` attribute to `metadata` interestingly loads metadata for all of the audio tracks, but when all of the elements are played - 6 of them freeze somewhere inbetween `0-4s` with `audio.readyState` being `1`
- Removing the audio element and adding it back doesn't trigger any additional network activity

**Possible causes**

Either it's a Chrome bug, or it is a Chrome feature, or it is a file format constraint.

Is there a way to make more than 10 audios to play on desktop Chrome without having to use the Web Audio API?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome only Loading 6 HTML5 audio tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004658/chrome-only-loading-6-html5-audio-tags)

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel No, that question was related to maximum allowed parallel downloads and the solution is outside of Chrome: need to add multiple domains for delivery, which I've tried. 6 is understandable. 10 is not :)

Comment: Same exact problem here... has anyone found a solution?