# HTML5 <audio> stalled on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio, svelte

I am working on an audioguide Svelte application, and I need to be able to play the audio tracks from a playlist.
Since I don't have the duration of files beforehand and I have to display it, this is what I am doing:

1. For each track, load the metadata with `<audio>` and update the duration
2. Once duration is fetched, remove the `<audio>` from the DOM

```
    {#if !loadedMetadata}
        <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-media-has-caption -->
        <audio hidden preload="metadata" 
            bind:duration 
            on:loadedmetadata={() => loadedMetadata = true} 
            on:stalled={() => console.log((id + 1) + ' stalled')}>
            <source src={url} type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    {/if}
```

**My problem:**
The audio elements get randomly stalled on Chrome, but not on Firefox or Safari. This doesn't seem to be caused by [Chrome only Loading 6 HTML5 audio tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004658/chrome-only-loading-6-html5-audio-tags): sometimes I have only 5 elements and they all get stalled, sometimes I have 11 and everything works fine.

Comment: Does it change something when it's done via js and not the markup? https://svelte.dev/repl/80308d86d1044e8a9acd59a4ca7818a3?version=3.49.0

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately no, I get the same result.